Why is the following method reference illegal?
I have some confusion about how method references work.
The following is an example from JLS 15.13.1:

An example of ambiguity is:
interface Fun<T,R> { R apply(T arg); } 

class C { 
    int size() { return 0; } 
    static int size(Object arg) { return 0; } 
    void test() { 
    Fun<C, Integer> f1 = C::size; 
      // Error: instance method size() 
      // or static method size(Object)? 
    } 
}


I tried to analyze this code to see what the method call referred to by the method reference should be.
According to JLS 15.13.1(Retain the relevant parts.):

• First, a type to search is determined:
– If the method reference expression has the form
ReferenceType ::[TypeArguments] Identifier, the type to search is the result of
capture conversion (§5.1.10) applied to ReferenceType.

So the type to search is the class type C.

• Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of
potentially applicable methods is identified:
– If the method reference expression has the form
ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier,
then the potentially applicable methods are:
› the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially
applicable (§15.12.2.1) for a method invocation which names
Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears
in the same class as the method reference expression; plus
› the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially
applicable for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity
n-1, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class
as the method reference expression.

So the methods int size() and int size(Object arg) are all potentially applicable.
The potentially applicable rules also require that parameters and arguments be potentially compatible. Is it unnecessary here because the types of the arguments for the invocation are not mentioned?

It says "the second search contains no non-static methods", but in this case the second search does contain a non-static method. I think you misread the double negative here.

Also, you are asking at least 3 different questions here: "Is it unnecessary here because the types of the arguments for the invocation are not mentioned?", "I don't understand why there is an error here", and "Is there anyone who could explain this part to me in detail?" at the end. Please [edit] your question so that it focuses on one problem only.

@Sweeper Oh, I think I asked a silly question. I have edited my question, leaving only "Is it unnecessary here because the types of the arguments for the invocation are not mentioned?" and I'm looking forward to your insights.

When you change the question to ask something totally different (which you should avoid in general) you should also adapt the title, to match your actual question. Besides that, I don’t understand the remaining question. Why should the requirement that the parameters and arguments must be potentially compatible depend on being mentioned again? Just change static int size(Object arg) to static int size(String arg) and you’ll see that it is not applicable anymore, as the parameter and argument type are not potentially compatible anymore.

@Holger I think that after changing static int size(Object arg) to static int size(String arg), it is still potentially applicable. According to the JLS, now assume there is a method call, "names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression", and then determine whether the modified method invocation is potentially applicable for this assumed method.They have the same name and the same arity.However, what about compatibility? It doesn't provide the parameter types of the assumed method.

@Holger Is this what the specification means?In addition, attach the link about potential applicability.

The functional interface provides the required types, i.e. C → Integer, to whom the method must be compatible.

@Holger   Of course, you are right. However, that is to be ensured in the subsequent steps. It has nothing to do with my question. We are currently discussing the "potentially applicable" step (right after determining the types to be searched).

I don’t see a second step in §15.13.1. that would remove methods from the set determined by §15.12.2.1. As far as I can see, the next step is determining the most specific method. Whilst §15.12.2.1 does contains a requirement that the arguments of the method invocation are potentially compatible.

@Holger  I'm referring to the paragraph "• Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:..." in 15.13.1. It describes the rules for identifying potentially applicable methods in method references. Then, if there are potentially applicable methods, they can go through the screening process from "Strict Invocation" to "Choosing the Most Specific Method."

@Holger The problem is that the conditions for identifying potentially applicable methods are not sufficient. As you mentioned, "Whilst §15.12.2.1 does contains a requirement that the arguments of the method invocation are potentially compatible." However, this paragraph doesn't provide the types of the arguments.

What do you mean with “doesn't provide the types of the arguments”?

And where did you get that “screening process from ‘Strict Invocation’ to ‘Choosing the Most Specific Method.’” from? §15.13.1. does not contain such a thing. Right after “a set of potentially applicable methods is identified” (which refers to §15.12.2.1), there is choosing the most specific applicable method.

@Holger I said, "doesn't provide the types of the arguments", which means exactly what it says on the surface. You agreed that to identify potentially applicable methods requires the potential compatibility between the arguments of the method invocation and the parameters of the member method. Step 2 in 15.13.1 (Second, given a targeted function type...) provides a hypothetical method invocation, but it doesn't provide the types of the arguments for that invocation.

Please, when I already told you that I don’t understand it, try to rephrase your concern instead of repeating it literally. I still don’t understand who is the one who ought to provide something when you say “this paragraph doesn't provide the types of the arguments”. Of course, it doesn’t. The program/source code provides the type arguments. In case of a method reference, it’s the functional signature of the target type. In case of your example, the target type is Fun<C, Integer> and the functional signature therefore C → Integer

@Holger Well, (I'm not sure if I've understood it wrongly). The second step in 15.13.1 of the specification says, "...for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression;". Does this mean that the specification assumes a method invocation (not provided by the source code.) in order to judge the potential applicability with a member method? Then, without providing the argument types of the method invocation, how can it judge the potential applicability?

Well, right at the beginning of §15.13.1., it is said: “The choice of compile-time declaration depends on a function type targeted by the expression, just as the compile-time declaration of a method invocation depends on the invocation's arguments”. That’s what I said, the target function type provides you with a functional signature that is to be used the same way you’d use the method arguments’ type for an ordinary invocation.
